# IndexError: list index out of range, animating sprite, character movement

Tags: python, pygame

im new to python, and recently encountered a problem when trying to animate the Sprite of my main character.
Code error is

> "IndexError: list index out of range".

The character moves a few pixels and then stops and the error is displayed, it never shows any animation.

```
import pygame
import sys
import os

pygame.display.set_mode()

class Adventurer(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.movex = 0
        self.movey = 0
        self.frame = 0

        self.runRight = []
        for i in range(1,6):
            img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Characters", "ADVENTURER", "runR" + str(i) + '.png'))
            img.convert_alpha()
            img.set_colorkey(ALPHA)
        self.runRight.append(img)
        self.image = self.runRight[0]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        #runningLeft
        self.runLeft = []
        for i in range(1,6):
            img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Characters", "ADVENTURER", "runL" + str(i) + '.png'))
            img.convert_alpha()
            img.set_colorkey(ALPHA)
        self.runLeft.append(img)
        self.image = self.runLeft[0]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def control(self,x,y): #control player movement
        self.movex += x
        self.movey += y

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x = self.rect.x + self.movex
        self.rect.y = self.rect.y + self.movey

        #moving left
        if self.movex < 0:
            self.frame += 1
            if self.frame > 6*ani:
                self.frame = 0
            self.image = self.runLeft[self.frame//ani]    

        #moving right
        if self.movex > 0:
            self.frame += 1
            if self.frame > 6*ani:
                self.frame = 0
            self.image = self.runRight[self.frame//ani]    


ALPHA = (1, 1, 1)

screenWidth = 900
screenHeight = 507

fps = 20
ani = 6
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.init()

world = pygame.display.set_mode([screenWidth, screenHeight])
backdrop = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Backgrounds", "Background1.jpg")).convert()
backdropbox = world.get_rect()

player = Adventurer()
player.rect.x = 0
player.rect.y = 435
player_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
player_list.add(player)
steps = 10 #pixels to move

main = True

while main == True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             pygame.quit(); sys.exit()
             main = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
                main = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == ord("a"):
                player.control(-steps,0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == ord("d"):
                player.control(steps, 0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == ord("w"):
                print ("jump")    

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == ord("a"):
                player.control(steps,0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == ord("d"):
                player.control(-steps,0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == ord("w"):
                print ("jump stop")



    world.blit(backdrop, backdropbox)
    player.update()
    player_list.draw(world)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(fps)
```

The idea is for the character to gice the idea of movement.
This is the error i get:

> ```
> FromScratch.py", line 51, in update self.image = self.runLeft[self.frame//ani]
>     IndexError: list index out of range
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code only the last image is append to the list, because the `.append` instruction is after the loop. It has to be done in the loop:

```py
self.runRight = []
for i in range(1,6):
    img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Characters", "ADVENTURER", "runR" + str(i) + '.png'))
    img.convert_alpha()
    img.set_colorkey(ALPHA)
    # -->
    self.runRight.append(img)
```

```py
self.runLeft = []
for i in range(1,6):
    img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Characters", "ADVENTURER", "runL" + str(i) + '.png'))
    img.convert_alpha()
    img.set_colorkey(ALPHA)
    # -->
    self.runLeft.append(img)
```

The *"list index out of range"* out of range error is caused by the look up of the image list. You've to use the modulo (`%`) operator, to calculate the integral remainder of a division by the number of images (See [operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html)):

```py
def update(self):
    # [...]

    if self.movex < 0:
        self.frame += 1
        self.image = self.runLeft[(self.frame//ani) % len(self.runLeft)]    

    if self.movex > 0:
        self.frame += 1
        self.image = self.runRight[(self.frame//ani) % len(self.runRight)]
```

According to the comment:

> [...] it moves quite fast [...]

Add `clock = pygame.time.Clock()` at the initialization and `clock.tick(60)` inside the game loop (right after `while main == True:`). See [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock). With the parameter to  [`.tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) you can throttle the speed:

```py
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while main == True:
    clock.tick(60)
    # [...]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked... it moves quite fast, i guess thats because fps are a bit high.

Comment: @IvnMzk You're welcome. To *"it moves quite fast"* see the last (new) section of the answer.

Comment: Yes, i figured that out... adjusted the fps and wrote "clock.tick(fps)"... that seems to work

Answer (score 0):

The line `self.runLeft.append(img)` is intended too little, placing it outside of the for loop. Therefore, only the last image is added to `self.runLeft`, so attempts to access the second through fifth elements of the list (when `self.frame` becomes greater than `ani`) raise an error instead of producing an animation.

Comment: thanks, i corrected that, but i still get the same error... maybe this isn't the best way to do animations...